# how to deal with wrong akka event in the akka journal

Tags: scala, akka

I am very new to scala and akka so forgive if this question is very lame.

I have build a reactive application and it creates events and stores perfectly in cassandra which I am using as journal.

There can be a scenario that my application might have some bug and I would have stored a wrong event in the journal.How would I deal with it? If I will release a new fixed version of application events after that will be right but I still be having a wrong event in my journal and during a restore it will play them wrong.